# OpenTelemetry swift CocoaPods

Tags: swift, cocoapods, open-telemetry, podspec

is it possible to install OpenTelemetry in a project via Cocoapods? The git has instructions only for packages
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-swift
in my project, you can only import libraries through pods, packages do not suit me.

I already tried to install through the pods, but I could not import

Comment: You might mimic `Package.swift` file and create your own pod spec, but all the needed dependencies might also need podspec...

Comment: is there an example of such an implementation? I can't understand what is meant

Comment: A Pod "lib", needs a `PodSpec`. It tells what are the files needed, dependencies, and other stuff. SPM equivalent is a `Package.swift`. See for instance Alamofire https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Alamofire.podspec vs https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Package.swift So you need to do the same (if possible) with https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-swift/blob/main/Package.swift